# jQuery add class after clicking

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I have a question. How can I do toggle for multiple divs using only one small code like this one down below. Any ideas?

```
var a = ["1","2","3"];
  $('#toggle'+a).click(function () {
  $('#slide'+a).toggleClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop over `a` array to bind click events to all buttons:

```
var a = ["1", "2", "3"];
a.forEach(function(i) {
    $('#toggle' + i).click(function () {
        $('#slide' + i).toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

But I would better set all toggle buttons common class like `<button id="toggle1" class="toggle">Toggle 1</button>` and go with something like this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    var index = this.id.replace('toggle', '');
    $('#slide' + index).toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me a lot. I spend on it something about hour because i don't know jQuery and i needed this. Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select by a class:

#### html

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

#### js

```
$('.foo').click(function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('bar');
});
```